# Python 3.6 - Using re.findall to extract substring from Array-Element

Tags: python, arrays, regex, python-3.x

I have had a longer break from Python and now I need your help again :)

I have an **array** looking like this:

```
['>lcl|NC_003078.1_gene_1 [gene=lacE] [locus_tag=SM_b21652] [location=1..1275]\n','>lcl|NC_003078.1_gene_2 [gene=lacF] [locus_tag=SM_b21653] [location=complement(22345..23337)]\n']
```

The array contains a lot more of entries, all looking like the examples provided. I want to extract one part of each element using Regex. The **part I want to extract** is

```
[location.....]
```

I use Regexr to build my Regexes and **I tried** this:

```
locationArray=[]
for entry in storageArray:
    location.Array.append((re.findall("(\[location=\d*|complement\(\d*\.\.\d*\)\]|\.\.\d*\]))",str(entry))))
print(locationArray)
```

When doing it with Regexr in the browser, the Regex seems to work out.

**Expected/desired output:**

```
['[location=...]','[location=...]' etc]
```

**Actual output:**

```
[['cE]', '_b21625]','[location=1','..1257]'],
```

Comparing to the input, parts have been taken from gene and locus_tag.
I do not understand, why :( did I get the array structure wrong? Is it about my Regex?

Help appreciated!

Nevertheless, this is not my final desired output. After extracting all the locations, I want to process them ending up with this:

```
Start:     1 End:  1275
Start: 22345 End: 23337
```

**Since I did not even make it to extract the location part, I am already asking here.**

Thanks for help. I also appreciate different approaches to fix the problem. Problably, my way is not the best to do this?

Comment: What you are trying to do is `\[location=[^\]]+\]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
a = ['>lcl|NC_003078.1_gene_1 [gene=lacE] [locus_tag=SM_b21652] [location=1..1275]\n','>lcl|NC_003078.1_gene_2 [gene=lacF] [locus_tag=SM_b21653] [location=complement(22345..23337)]\n']
for i in a:
    val = re.findall("location\=.*?]", i)[0]     #Find Location.
    val = re.findall("\d+", val)                 #Find start and end.
    print("Start: {0} End:  {1}".format(val[0], val[1]))
```

**output:**

```
Start: 1 End:  1275
Start: 22345 End:  23337
```